# Where is lipo located in iOS SDK 9

Tags: ios, lipo

With iOS SDK 8 I could locate `lipo` util with following code:

```
IPHONE_OS_PLATFORM_PATH = $(shell xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-path)
ARM_DEV_DIR = $(IPHONE_OS_PLATFORM_PATH)/Developer/usr/bin
```

And run like this (Boost library example):

```
$(ARM_DEV_DIR)/lipo -create $(foreach arch,$(ARM_ARCHITECTURES),$(IPHONE_BUILD_DIR)/$(arch)/libboost.a) $(foreach arch,$(SIM_ARCHITECTURES),$(IPHONESIM_BUILD_DIR)/$(arch)/libboost.a) -o $(IOS_LIBBOOST)
```

Now there is no `lipo` in that location. How to get location?

Update #1

Same thing with `ar`. Looks like they where removed from iOS SDK and available only as OSX versions in `/opt/local/bin`.

Comment: `lipo` is not any part of iOS or of any SDK. It is part of Xcode.

Comment: But looks like previously it was because that script was working without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:; xcrun --sdk iphoneos -f lipo
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo

:; xcrun --sdk iphoneos -f ar
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar
```

Comment: Is there any difference with OSX versions?

Comment: I believe `lipo` supports all of their platforms in a single executable. Same for `ar`.